# Plugin for editable table list

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface, treeview

I am looking for a plugin (jQuery or any alternative method) that produces a list of tables with the table values expanding upon user click, and the table being editable.

I've made a (very) crude image to visualise what I'm looking for:

[image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/ms2jdg.jpg]

I prefer coding in PHP and would like to avoid ASP. The tables will be connected to an SQL database.

Is there anything out there or will I have to write the code from scratch?

I've tried to be as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [www.jtable.org/](http://www.jtable.org/)

jTable is a jQuery plugin that is used to create AJAX based CRUD tables without coding HTML or Javascript.It is an open source plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this one:

```
http://www.datatables.net/
```

If you could have more specifications please update your question and I'll be glad to update this answer.

Comment: Can you explain or provide a link as to how I could apply that plugin to this specific problem? I understand how to use that plugin to create an editable table but how do I make the table like a tree view?

Comment: Calum, the plugin is very well documented